# MoveIt Tutorial not working

Tags: ros, moveit, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to run the beginning MoveIt tutorials.  In Ubuntu 12.04, Groovy, I have tried the setups both for the PR2 Robot example, and the Groovy/Robonaut example.  I have not had luck getting either to work.  For the Robonaut, the robot is not displayed in RViz.  For the PR2, the class pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin is having an issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63046/moveit-tutorial-not-working/) by [ericbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4931/ericbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-05-19**:
Please provide more detail about your situation: how you have installed moveIt (source, packages, etc.), what steps you've tried running, and exactly what errors you're seeing.  The MoveIt tutorials are working for other users, so providing more detail will help us troubleshoot what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eric,

I believe your issue for the PR2 was solved:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/issues/18

I cannot get the Robonaut gazebo simulator to come up either - I have put a ticket for this on their github page. I will update the MoveIt! page for that robot once that ticket is fixed.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0